# Accessing Task properties in different subproject in Gradle

Tags: gradle

For the sake of asking this question, I have a trivial subproject defined as:

```
project("data-source-config") {
  def projectName = "data-source-config"

  jar {
    baseName = "${projectName}_$scalaVersion"
    version = "$version"
  }

}
```

I would really like to be able to refer to the full output jar name in a separate subproject.

Something like:

```
project("another-subproject") {
  def projectName = "another-subproject"

  println(:data-source-config:jar.getProperty("archiveName")) // I don't know the correct syntax
}
```

I can see that the JAR task has the archiveName property in the docs here: 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveFileName

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
project("another-subproject") {
  evaluationDependsOn ':data-source-config' 
  println project(':data-source-config').tasks['jar'].archiveName
}
```

Comment: This answer was automatically tagged "low quality". As explained in the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ("Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."), please edit your answer to tell the OP what he's doing wrong, how you reasoned and what your code is about, to show that you understood the question and to make benefit both the OP and future visitors.

Comment: This answer is actually is exactly what I wanted and needed - in my question I asked for 'something like the code block I provided' and got the exact, working code block I needed in response.